# CSS Compass custom sprite name

Tags: sass, sprite, compass-sass

Now if we generate sprite image using compass

```
@import "imgs/*.png";
@include all-imgs-sprites;
```

we ill gate in our .css classes like this

```
.imgs-<imagename>
```

is it possible to delete "imgs" part? I need only `.<imagename>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case don't use the magical `all`. It's not as convenient, but works fine. Just `@import` the sprite and `@include` the individual images in custom classes:

```
@import "imgs/*.png";

.circle {
    @include imgs-sprite('circle');
}

.square {
    @include imgs-sprite('square');
}
```

Make your life simpler by DRYing it up:

```
@each $file in circle, square {
    .#{$file} {
        @include imgs-sprite($file);
    }
}
```